# Defauft gateway permanent change in centos 7

Tags: linux, centos

i have 2 nic attached to my VM(centos 7) 1st is NAT, and 2nd is Host only adapter.
the hostonly adapter has become the default gateway, and is restricting my internet access, i want to make my NAT (1st enp0s3) to become the default gateway.
i have tried this, but still upon reboot the host only becomes the default gateway.

```
#    route del default gw 192.168.43.1
#    route add default gw 10.0.2.2 metric 100
#    route add default gw 192.168.43.1 metric 101
```

current scenario.

```
[root@node1 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s8
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s8
```